# Create an identical pod using different values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, skaffold

I currently have an app deployed on k8s using Skaffold. Using Helm I have defined the main `deployment.yaml` manifest as a template and used a `values.yaml` to insert other values into that deployment template.

What I would like to do is have 2 deployments of the same app using different values from the `values.yaml` file. So essentially 2 pods running the same application aside from the different values provided, for instance a `my-app-blue` pod and `my-app-green` pod. Is there anyway that I can do this without having to use a whole new `deployment.yaml` file? Sorry for any ambiguity I'm new to K8s, Helm, and Skaffold.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
   name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
   replicas: {{ .Values.blue-deployment.replicas }}
   template:
      spec:
         containers:
            -  name: {{ .Values.blue-deployment.name }}
               image: {{ .Values.blue-deployment.image }}
```

values.yaml

```
namespace: my-app
name: app

blue-deployment:
   name: blue
   image: my-image
   replicas: 1
   env:
      - name: COLOR
        value: 'blue'

green-deployment:
   name: green
   image: my-image
   replicas: 1
   env:
      - name: COLOR
        value: 'green'
```

skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta
kind: Config
build:
   artifacts:
      - image: blue-deployment
        context: './'
deploy:
   - name: my-application
     chartPath: kubernetes
     valuesFiles:
        - kubernetes/values.yaml
     namespace: my-app
```

directory structure:

```
myApp/
kubernetes/
   templates/
      myApp/
         deployment.yaml
   values.yaml
skaffold.yaml
Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a loop. [helm range](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action)

values.yaml

```yaml
namespace: my-app
name: app

deps:
  - name: blue
    image: my-image
    replicas: 1
    env:
      - name: COLOR
        value: 'blue'

  - name: green
    image: my-image
    replicas: 1
    env:
      - name: COLOR
        value: 'green'
```

deployment.yaml

```yaml
{{- $i, $v := range .Values.deps}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
   name: {{ $v.name }}
spec:
   replicas: {{ $v.replicas }}
   template:
      spec:
         containers:
            -  name: {{ $v.name }}
               image: {{ $v.image }}
{{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   namespace: my-app
   name: blue
spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
      spec:
         containers:
            -  name: blue
               image: my-image
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   namespace: my-app
   name: green
spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
      spec:
         containers:
            -  name: green
               image: my-image
```

Comment: This appears to work for the most part, however when using the loop to create 2 deployments it results in `ErrImagePull` for some reason... Cannot work out why it's causing it. If I remove the loop and just have one deployment the image pulls fine, so it must be being caused by the loop for some reason

Comment: How does looping affect image pulls? These are two completely unrelated things. You can try to unroll the loop, or even submit the yaml of two deployments directly to test it. This cannot be related to the loop.

Comment: Or you can test it by replacing it with two nginx image, it cannot be related to the loop